# SharePoint 2019 - result "http error" with new ssl

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

New SharePoint 2019 On premise environment. Search works perfectly fine when used in "http://sharepointserver/" but when tried over the configured https url "https://sharepoint.example.com" the search gives the error below. Crawl logs show that it can crawl the data successfully over the https.

Additional information:

- sharepointserver.domain1.com - Internal AD Domain - AAM: Default
- sharepoint.example.com - External Domain added to DNS - AAM: Intranet

[image: http-error]

I also checked the following:

- All services are started
- Restarted SharePoint Timer service
- Search Service is associated with the web app
- Disabled Windows Server Firewall but still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Extended the storage of the disk (we had 50gb free before, now over 100gb) and it somehow started working.